# Normal tangent vector and normal vector problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the following vector function.
$$r(t) = \left\langle 2t \cdot \sqrt{2}, e^{2t}, e^{-2t}\right\rangle$$

(a) Find the unit tangent and unit normal vectors $T(t)$ and $N(t)$.
$T(t) =$
$N(t) =$

(b) Use this formula to find the curvature.
$κ(t) =$

I am getting bogged down in the math. I know how to calculate the three things but I am having trouble getting the derivative of $T(t)$ after solving for it. I have gotten $T(t)$ to equal $$\frac{1}{2 e^{2t} + 2 e^{-2t}} \left\langle 2 \cdot \sqrt{2}, 2 e^{2t},-2 e^{-2t}\right\rangle$$.

Thank you!

Comment: It's fricking duplicate - the same question third time by the same user. :|

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304487/unit-tangent-and-unit-normal-vectors-calculus-iii-question and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304320/calculus-iii-vector-question-tt-nt-kt The first link already contains enough hints, imho.

Comment: I still cannot get an answer, zaarcis. Your condescending responses are not helping me get any further aid from anyone, either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine...

$$\left|\left|\left(2\sqrt 2\,,\,2e^{2t}\,,\,-2e^{-2t}\right)\right|\right|^2=8+4(e^{4t}+e^{-4t})=4(e^t+e^{-t})^2=16\cosh^2 t$$

Comment: And now how would I get N(t)?

Comment: Er...you supposed to know that, aren't you? You need a *perpendicular* vector to the tangent one, then normalize and etc...

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the unit vector for T(t)...