# Curvature of a Vector Function $(k(t))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$r(t) = (2t \sqrt{2}, 2e^{2t}, -2e^{-2t})$$

Find the curvature using the formula $\displaystyle \frac{|T'(t)|}{|r'(t)|}$.

I have the denominator for the formula but am having trouble working through the math for the numerator of the formula.

So far I have $T'(t) = \dfrac{1}{(e^3t+1)^2}\left(-2\sqrt{2}e^{5t}+4\sqrt{2}e^{2t}, 2e^{7t}+8e^{4t},6e^{3t}\right)$.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability if you format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please make sure I edited it properly. Regards

Comment: Can you post what you have so far for $|T'(t)|$?

Comment: I have T'(t) = 1/(e^3t+1)^2{-2*squareroot(2)e^5t+4*squareroot(2)e^2t, 2e^7t+8e^4t,6e^3t}

Comment: It's better to edit such things into the question itself, as I just did. Please check it to make sure I interpreted your formula correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304487/unit-tangent-and-unit-normal-vectors-calculus-iii-question/304521#304521) post, you have$$T'(t)={2\over( 2e^{2t}+ 2e^{-2t})^2}\cdot F(t)$$

Where 
$$F(t)={  (e^{2t}+e^{-2t})} \bigl< 0, 4e^{2t}, 4 e^{-2t} \bigr>
-({2e^{2t}-2e^{-2t}})  \bigl< 2\sqrt2, 2e^{2t}, -2 e^{-2t} \bigr>$$

The first component of $F(t)$ is
$$
0-2\sqrt2 \cdot  (2e^{2t}-2e^{-2t}).
$$
The second component of $F$ is
$$
(e^{2t}+e^{-2t})\cdot 4e^{2t}-2e^{2t}(2e^{2t}-2e^{-2t})
=4e^{4t}+4-4e^{4t}+4=8.
$$
The third component of $F$ is
$$
(e^{2t}+e^{-2t})\cdot 4e^{-2t}+2e^{-2t}(2e^{2t}-2e^{-2t})
=4+4e^{-4t}+4-4e^{-4t}=8 .
$$

Thus 
$$\eqalign{
T'(t)&=
{2\over( 2e^{2t}+ 2e^{-2t})^2}\cdot 
\bigl<  -2\sqrt2 \cdot  (2e^{2t}-2e^{-2t})\ ,  8\ , 8  \bigr>\cr
&={e^{4t}\over2( e^{4t}+ 1)^2}\cdot 
\bigl<  -4\sqrt2 \cdot e^{-2t} (e^{4t}-1)\ ,  8\ , 8 \bigr>\cr
&={e^{4t}\over ( e^{4t}+ 1)^2}\cdot 
\bigl<  -2\sqrt2 \cdot e^{-2t} (e^{4t}-1)\ ,  4\ ,4\bigr>.\cr
}
$$

So
$$\eqalign{
|T'(t)|&=\Bigl|\ {e^{4t}\over ( e^{4t}+ 1)^2}\cdot 
\bigl<  -2\sqrt2 \cdot e^{-2t} (e^{4t}-1)\ ,  4\ ,4\bigr>\Bigr|\cr
&={e^{4t}\over ( e^{4t}+ 1)^2}\cdot \bigl|
\bigl<  -2\sqrt2 \cdot e^{-2t} (e^{4t}-1)\ ,  4\ ,4\bigr>\bigr|\cr
&={e^{4t}\over ( e^{4t}+ 1)^2}\cdot 
\sqrt{  8 \cdot \bigl(e^{-2t} (e^{4t}-1)\bigr)^2+32}.\cr
}
$$

Hopefully, I made no errors (I will check it momentarily) ...

Answer (score 0):

Just do what it says: compute $T(t)$, then compute $T'(t)$, then compute $|T'(t)|$. It's the sort of problem where you just follow your nose and do the calculations.

Comment: I cannot get a simplified answer for |T'(t)|!

Comment: Who says you're supposed to get something simple?

Comment: You are unlikely to get anything simple. In general $T(t)$ will have a square root in the denominator, unless it happens to simplify in a particular problem. Then for $T'(t)$ you have to take the derivative of the complicated expression for $T(t)$. This is why the alternate formula $k(t) = |r'(t)\times r''(t)|/(|r'(t)|^3)$ is useful, because it does not require working directly with $T$. However, your question requires the use of $T$.

Comment: It's just so messy.